# Remembering Form Checkbox State With Initial Default Value

Tags: php, html, forms, post

I've got a form with a checkbox. When a user first visits the page, I want the checkbox to be 'checked'. However, if they uncheck the box and then submit the page, I want it to remain unchecked (and to remain checked if they submit the page with it checked).

To determine when it has been checked and the form submitted, I'm currently doing:

```
<input type='checkbox' class='seeAll' name='seeAll' value='true' <?php if ($_POST['seeAll'] == 'true') echo checked; ?>>
```

This works great for leaving the box checked when needed, however, how would I go about ensuring it stays unchecked if they submit it that way, while also being checked if they revisit the page (such as by re-entering the URL)?

Thanks!

Comment: If you want it permanent use database or file, otherwise you can use $_SESSION or even cookies

Comment: But $_SESSION variable wouldn't work to recheck the box if they revisited the page via any means other than the submit button. It'd remember the last checked state no matter what, right?

Comment: that's why I added there option to store it in database, You didn't mention if it is part of member or free for all, that depends you know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know why it took me so long to come up with this answer, but after struggling with this, I realized I could just check the value of the checkbox via the `$_POST`, as I was doing before *and* could check if the user arrived at the page by some means other than the submit button by doing this:

```
<?php if(($_POST['seeAll'] == 'true') || !isset($_POST['submit'])) echo checked; ?>
```

If the user submitted the form, than `isset($_POST['submit'])` will be true and so if that's the case *and* `$_POST['seeAll']` is empty, them obviously the user submitted an unchecked box. If `isset($_POST['submit'])` is false, then the user arrived on the page without submitting the form and I should check the checkbox as the 'default'.

So then my whole `<input>` tag looks like this:

```
<input type='checkbox' class='seeAll' name='seeAll' value='true' <?php if(($_POST['seeAll'] == 'true') || !isset($_POST['submit'])) echo checked; ?>>
```

Works just as I need!

Comment: Either your specifications were very unclear or your solution doesnt work. If the user browses away and then comes back to the page, it will "forget" the state of the check box.

Comment: Perhaps my explanation was unclear, but that's what I wanted. From above, `while also being checked if they revisit the page (such as by re-entering the URL)?` So ONLY remember state if they're being put back on the page by the submit button. That's why I initially responded to your answer below.

Comment: Gotcha, I see the difference btwn what you wanted and what I wrote now.

Comment: This is an excellent solution! I had the same problem today, and your answer got me on the right track. My only suggestion would be to change the first condition in your IF statement from "if(($_POST['seeAll'] == 'true'" to "if(!empty($_POST['seeAll']" The reason being, empty()  also tests whether the box is checked, AND it also guards against PHP warnings that would otherwise occur 9and fill up your logs) whenever the 'undefined index' 'seeAll' is referenced. that will happen whenever the visitor has not yet submitted the form.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE:: This is differs from OP's question because it will remember the value of the checkbox even if the user goes away from the page (say, to www.facebook.com) and then back to the page. The OP wanted it to only remember the value of the checkbox when the page was posted to.

If you want a non permanent method you can use $_SESSION :

```
<?php
    if (!isset($_SESSION)) {
        session_start();
    }   

    if ($_POST['seeAll'] == 'true' || !isset($_SESSION['seeAll'])) {
        $_SESSION['seeAll'] = true;
    } else {
        $_SESSION['seeAll'] = false;
    }
?>


<form method="POST">
    <input type='checkbox' class='seeAll' name='seeAll' value='true' 
        <?php if ($_SESSION['seeAll']) echo 'checked'; ?>
    />
    <input type='submit'/>
</form>
```

see: http://php.net/manual/en/session.examples.basic.php

Comment: This will last as long as the session does.

Comment: Wouldn't this cause the default (checked) to not be set if the user revisits the page through some means besides the 'submit' button. Like if they re-enter the URL, I'd like the checkbox to go back to the default 'checked', even if it was unchecked the last time they submitted the form.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to use both `$_SESSION[""]` and `$_POST[""]`.
(*See explanation and code below*)

EXPLANATION

1. If `$_SESSION["loadcount"]` is not set, set it to 0.
2. With each `if (isset($_POST["submit"]`, increase `$_SESSION["load count"]` by +1.
3. In the 'checked' option of the input type="checkbox", echo PHP. If `if ($_SESSION["loadcount"] == 0)` echo 'checked'. (Sets the checkbox to an initially checked state.)
4. Else, if `(isset($_POST["agree"]` echo 'checked', to remember the state checked by the user. (Remember the checked state set by user.

CODE

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <?php  // session_firstload.php

            // Check if $_SESSION is not set, set $_SESSION loadcount to 0
            if (!isset($_SESSION["loadcount"])) 
                $_SESSION["loadcount"] = 0;

            // When the user submits using POST Method
            if (isset($_POST["submit"]))
            {
                // Increase $_SESSION["loadcount"] by +1
                $_SESSION["loadcount"] = $_SESSION["loadcount"] + 1;
            }

            // Echoing for Debugging / Understanding
            echo $_SESSION["loadcount"];
        ?>

        <form action="session_firstload.php" method="post">
            <input id="agree" type="checkbox" name="agree" 
            <?php 
                // If Check the Checkbox is $_SESSION["loadcount"] == 0
                // Else 'remember' with (isset($_POST["agree"]
                if ($_SESSION["loadcount"] == 0) 
                        echo "checked";
                    else
                    {
                        if (isset($_POST["agree"]))
                            echo "checked";
                    }
            ?>
            >I Agree<br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: A minor detail, close your br tags. `<br/>`

Comment: In HTML, the <br> tag has no end tag says http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp

Comment: Well, please check out: [w3fools.com](http://www.w3fools.com/) for evidence of w3schools poor quality... then again, while `<br>` tags will function properly, HTML is a markup, so every tag should begin and end. If a tag is self contained such as `<br>`, `<img>` and others, a tag may define the expected result..... in this case, you are correct. br tags are self contained, but having a closed br tag would indicate an XHTML document, and thats where I got confused. For a reference, [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/br) is vastly superior to w3schools.

Comment: @Bonatti advise taken. Thanks for the MDN link.